# How to write subquery in select statement in hive with additional column whose one single value is obtained by sum of certain rows

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

Suppose there is a table with columns as details of student's performance.

```
Student(name,subject,marks,verdict('pass'/'fail')).
```

I need to have another column in this table which will be - the sum of marks of the subjects in which a particular student fails.

In MySQL I could have written :

```
select *,
select (sum(marks) from Student where name=s.name and verdict='fail')
from Student s;
```

But it doesn't work in hive.

> ERROR: Unsupported SubQuery Expression Invalid subquery. Subquery in SELECT could only be top-level expression.

What can be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using  left join on subquery

```
  select s.*, t.marks
  from Student s
  left join  (
    select (name ,sum(marks) marks
    from Student 
    where verdict='fail'
    group by name)
  ) t on t.name = s.name
```

eventually try add  a proper index on  table student column name

Comment: Is there any other way if the Student table is too large. Since otherwise JOIN will be computationally expensive.

Comment: Your question is about an error and based on your comment my answer 
 resolve this  .  ..  .. computationally  expensive  ? .. could be  .. you can add  index  for avoid this  .. answer  updated  with index  suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    `name`, 
    `verdict`,
    concat_ws('|', collect_set(`subject`)),
    sum(`marks`)
from Student
group by name,verdict
```

Comment: is group_concat is supported in hive ?

Comment: Sorry missing the keyword `hive`. Updated for hive.